# PHP session variable doesn't work on pages with rewritten URLs

Tags: php, session

I have the variable $_SESSION['logged_in'] which is set when a user logged in and unset during the logout process. I have a navigation menu included on all pages which has the following code inside it:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    ?>
    <li><a href="http://absoluteurl/mylists.php">My Lists</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://absoluteurl/list/logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
    <?php
    }
    else{
    ?>
        <li><a href="http://absoluteurl/list/register.php">Sign Up</a></li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Now, on most pages this works fine - it displays the proper navigation items depending on whether the user is logged in. But I have some pages with URLs rewritten for SEO, and on these pages it doesn't work - it always shows the 'Sign Up' option as if the user wasn't logged in.

Note that the navigation menu is in a separate file which is included on the pages using 'include'. If I echo the session variable elsewhere on the page, it works fine - it just doesn't work from the included file.

Comment: How are you including the navigation file?

Comment: `<?php include('http://absoluteurl/include/new_header.php'); ?>`

Comment: thats your problem then. You need to include the file locally, not via it's URL.

Comment: Oh well. Silly mistake. Using relative links instead fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are calling [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before including the menu? ( of course it would be batter to make that call inside the include )

Comment: session_start() is called on the beginning of every page. Wouldn't it be redundant to re-do it inside the included file?

Comment: ...and starting the session inside the include doesn't change anything. Could there be a server setting in php.ini which is creating the problem? I'm asking as the server I'm working on currently had some really weird settings there.